# Sqoop: Import several tables from different SQL DBs into a single CSV in HDFS?

Tags: sql, hadoop, sqoop

With Sqoop I need to import several SQL tables into a single CSV file in HDFS. In other words I need to do something similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE all AS SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *  
  FROM user_1
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT *  
  from user_2
) tmp;
```

Is it possible to do this in Sqoop, providing that tables `user_1` and `user_2` exist in different DBs?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, You can't able to import tables from different databases at a time. But you can import all the tables from the particular database and then import the next database tables. But you can do like this,

```
sqoop import \
  --query 'SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a JOIN b on (a.id == b.id) WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
  -m 1 --target-dir /user/foo/joinresults
```

Comment: On import I need to concatenate tables from different DBs into a single CSV file, not just import them.

Comment: Yes, you can do this by using query parameter.

Comment: Tables are from different DBs. What query is in this case?

Comment: Now see the above query, it would help.